# Going to gyms in Japan

Tags: japan, health, activities, language-barrier

I'm planning a trip to Japan and was wanting to do a Gold's Gym there and am curious how it'd compare to a gym in the USA.

So with gyms in the USA I'll often go there with a drawstring backpack with my gym clothes in it. I'll change and then go workout with my drawstring backpack beside me (I don't use the lockers since I've had stuff stolen from them before and don't intend to have it stolen again). Is doing that okay in Japan as well?

Also, I read somewhere that you're supposed to take a different pair of shoes to work out in in Japanese gyms. Is this true? In the USA I normally work out in the same shoes that I went to work in and walked about the city in. ie. I have just one pair of shoes and I wear it everywhere. Do I need to get two pairs of shoes to do gyms (or other stuff) in Japan?

Comment: I have one tip for you. Stay clear of jackie chan while your there.

Comment: Isn't jackie chan from china? :P

Comment: I don't know, I'm not good with geography.

Comment: It's really difficult to get anything stolen in Japan. It's possibly mostly likely in a busy guesthouse or hostel with too many foreign travellers for everybody to know everybody.

Comment: Anything still missing in the answer I gave? I am happy to elaborate more if you feel you need more info!

Answer (score 12):

1. You cannot go to every shop as a visitor without getting a membership. check the website for the location where you want to go and look if the have a visitor (ビジター) package.
2. Depending on the location, they might require you to speak Japanese. Since Gym facilities have a legal responsibility towards your health, they have to make sure that they explain everything to you, including the machines etc. If they cannot do so in Japanese, they will either have to have English-speaking staff or simply will refuse you to enter. That means also that you will have to stick to the rules they tell you. If you are used to do things differently in the USA than what they tell you, better forget about what you know and do as they say, specially if you want to be a walk-in guest.
3. You will have to bring spare shoes. They will not let you train in your street shoes. All other facilities are depending on the location normally.
4. The chance that something will get stolen from your locker in Japan is very, very, very low. They rather come running behind you if you forget something.

Comment: So even if I have Gold's gym membership in the USA that wouldn't count as membership for a Gold's gym in Japan?

Comment: Not sure about the US, but their UK site says *"With international clubs you will need to collect a special passport from your club to gain access whilst on holiday or business abroad for a period of 2 weeks."* http://www.goldsgym.co.uk/index.php?main_page=page&id=6