# is this a chip & signature amex?

Tags: payment-cards

[image]

Well it looks like it has a chip in it so idk.

I ask because I'll be doing some international traveling soon and would like a [chip & signature amex](http://chipandsignature.americanexpress.com/).

Comment: Are you sure that this is the right forum to ask this question?  I'd ask American Express.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about specific card held by the user.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about money

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be better on money.stackexchange.com - there's no specific travel question in here, IMHO.

Comment: Well let's find out shall we?: http://money.stackexchange.com/q/27142/9984 And in any event if this question is off topic because it might fit in money.stackexchange.com then why is my other +8 question on topic when it could be seemingly posted in fitness.stackexchange.com?: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22880/4868

Comment: No. This is an [ExpressPay](https://www295.americanexpress.com/cards/loyalty.do?page=expresspay) chip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, but that is not what a traditional chip and pin/signature card looks like.  The chip is gold or silver colored and looks quite similar to SIM cards found in most mobile phones:

[image]

If a Card has an EMV chip, you will see a small metal square on the front of the card above the account number like the one pictured above.  Amex details all of this information on their website [here](http://chipandsignature.americanexpress.com/).  It clearly shows what the card looks like in the Amex promo video and it is not the one that you have referenced above:

[image]

Comment: The picture shown in the question shows a chip in an American Express Blue, which looks different from Visas/MC or Debit Cards and details you link is the ones linked in the Question.

Comment: The chip and pin/signature technology is standardized across carriers.  All chip and pin/signature cards will have a similar looking gold or silver chip directly above the account number.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help since it shows American Express Platinum a different card from AMEX Blue, and if you read the FAQ it suggest calling AMEX to receive one.  Your answer doesn't answer the question at all since again Amex BLUE shown on the original picture doesn't look the same as the rest of the cards.

Comment: The question is "is this a chip & signature amex?"  the answer is no per my reasoning above.

Comment: The answer is you don't know since you can't check.  Amex may provide you with Chip & Signature Card that looks exactly like the one in the picture.  The fact that they show a different card in the commercial doesn't mean this card isn't.

Comment: More specifically [Amex Blue](http://ficoforums.myfico.com/t5/Credit-Cards/American-Express-EMV-Chip-For-Most-Cards/td-p/2437583) is available with EMV chip.  So whether or not this one fits in this category is an AMEX question only.

Comment: I have answered the question that was being asked.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1.  The gold/silver contacts must be in exactly that shape and position so chip readers can interface with the card.  If they're not there, and they're clearly missing from the OP's card, it's not a chip card.

Comment: @jpatokal What's shown in picture is a card with a chip that uses non contact RF reader.  You can use it simply by waving it next to the reader.  You can see those installed in Duane Reade in New York and elsewhere.

Comment: @Karlson There may well be *a* chip on the card (and I have a Visa payWave card myself), but it's not what is meant by a "chip and signature" card that will work overseas.

Comment: @jpatokal Chip and Signature is just a chip that is capable of communicating ISO/IEC 7816-3 with the receiving terminal there is nothing to say what is the physical method of comm should be. And the answer provides no answer to the question because there is no information as far as I can tell about which AMEX Blue cards are chip & signature enabled if any.  So this answer only provides an opinion with the backup of the exact same link as posted in the question.  Which isn't really an answer, just an interpretation of promotional material by AMEX

Comment: I genuinely don't get what you're objecting to here.  Right now, in the real world, chip & PIN/signature cards have to be inserted into a reader that makes physical contact with the card, and from the picture a) it's clear that the card is incapable of doing this, so the card will thus not be usable as a chip & signature card overseas.  It might work as an AmEx Expresspay card now, or it might work with shiny new readers from the future, but that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: I agree - +1 reasonable to jpatokal. I think Karlson's answer is valid (hence my marking it as such) and using jpatokal's logic even if I posted a picture of a piece of tissue asking if that was a chip and signature card the correct answer would be "impossible to say because it's possible the toilet tissue has, within it, the chip and signature protocol implemented within it" (even if no reader exists that could read it). No offense to Karlson but I'd downvote all of his comments if comments could be downvoted.