# Pre-paid debit card in Canada

Tags: canada, money, payment-cards

As government taxes on credit/debit card transactions occurring outside my country are high (traveller's checks/cards too), the cheapest way to pay my expenses is to buy Canadian dollars at an exchange store before leaving. The downside is carrying so much money, so I figured I could buy a prepaid debit card once in Canada.

I searched for such cards, but I either found some that require permanent resident status while most others are limited to $500. I'd be interested in a cheap (ie. low/no taxes, easy withdraw when leaving) card with a limit of at least 1500 to CA$2000.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about money

Comment: @ansur If so, why are there so many questions like it?

Comment: You mean questions like http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22899/9669 that was closed?

Answer (score 1):

A debit card in Canada is slightly different from one in other countries. In Canada a debit card connects to a bank account, and you deposit money at the bank to then use it.

You can get a pre-paid credit card in Canada that you can buy in denominations and  doesn't need to be registered.

Does your country not have credit cards?

Comment: I have an international credit card, but the government taxes on every transaction are exceptionally high. Are you sure they're all tied to bank accounts? Example: https://www.paypower.ca/How-It-Works ; looks like "buy and use", but limited to $500 and only for permanent residents.

Comment: @user9744 Those are the same as prepaid credit cards here. A debit will always be tied to a bank account. Are you sure you get taxed on purchases you make outside of the country? That seems ridiculous.

Comment: Brazilian government is ridiculous, and that's how it works, unfortunately.